# Template value from class declaration in constructor definition

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I use template to deduce required static array length. Header file looks like:

```
template<uint8_t LENGTH>
class Foo
{
   int array[LENGTH];
   Foo();
}
```

I want to use `LENGTH` value in constructor definition in cpp file, somewhat similiar to:

```
Foo::Foo()
{
   for(uint8_t i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++)
   {
      //do_stuff
   }
}
```

So far I've done this by assigning `LENGTH` value to another variable in header file. How can I do this?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Small advice: leave upper-case names exclusively for macros.

Comment: n.m. - you're right, my bad.

Comment: *"constructor definition in cpp file"*: You might read [why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).

Comment: I think the syntax you are looking for is `template<uint8_t Length> Foo<Length>::Foo() {  for(uint8_t i = 0; i < Length; i++) {/*..*/}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't separate templates into a header file and a source file, the whole thing needs to be implemented in the header file. If you want to know why, you can read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/4284627). So you need to implement the whole thing in the header file:

```
template<uint8_t length>
class Foo{
private:
    int array[length];

public:
    Foo(){
        for(uint8_t i = 0; i < length; i++){
            //do_stuff
        }
    }
};
```

If you do this, you won't have any problem using `length` in the constructor.

Also note that you forgot the `;` at the end of the class definition. That's a mistake that could cause a compiler error. Also, it's best to use entirely upper-case names only for macros, so I called it `length` instead of `LENGTH`. I also suggest that you explicitly say if attributes and methods are public or private by adding `public:` or `private:`. By default, they're always private.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate through an entire array in C++ 11, just use:

```
for(auto &it: array){
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this will do for example I gave, but reason I want exact value is I need to do some calculation based on it, not only as an iterator.